# Convert cassandra row RDD to array of tuples

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Am trying to read the data from cassandra table and store the values in a array. My RDD looks like below

columns: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[3] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15

How to store these values in to a array without column names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iterator` followed by `toArray`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val arrayRDD: RDD[Array[AnyRef]] = rdd.map(_.iterator.toArray)
```

or `columnValues` method:

```
val arrayRDD: RDD[IndexedSeq[AnyRef]] = rdd.map(_.columnValues)
```

but generally speaking is rather useless unless you have any use for an `Array[AnyRef]`.

In practice it makes more sense to use type aware getter methods like `getInt`, `getString`. If data you want to extract is homogeneous you can map over indices or column names:

```scala
val cols: Array[String] = ??? // Array of column names of the same type
rdd.map(row => cols.map(row.getString(_)))
```

or

```
val colsIdxs: Array[Int] = ??? // Array of column indices of the same type
rdd.map(row => colsIdxs.map(row.getString(_)))
```

If you want to extract heterogeneous values you can use tuples with the same getter methods as above.